# fxform2 - determine the form is valid

Tags: javafx-8

I'm ising FxForm2 library with validation enabled in a javafx project. 
I Want to be able to determine the whole form is valid before say enabling a "next" button.

but did not find a method in then api that can help me do that.

Maybe someone knows how to do it or can guide me for the place I can find more doc on it.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [getConstraintViolations](http://dooapp.github.io/FXForm2/2.2.6/site/core/apidocs/com/dooapp/fxform/AbstractFXForm.html#getConstraintViolations()) method on your FXForm object to retrieve all violated constraints if any.